# Add two NSStrings together (numbers)

Tags: objective-c, nsnumber

im trying this:

```
    NSNumber *num1;
    NSNumber *num2;
    self.addNumberOfRoundsText.text = [num1 stringValue];
    self.numberOfRoundsText.text = [num2 stringValue];
    NSNumber *sum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([num1 intValue] + [num2 intValue])];
    NSLog(@"%@", [sum stringValue]);
```

For some reason, the console keeps outputting `0` im not sure if there is something i am missing. I just want to get the `text` from two UITextField's and add them. Then output them to the console. Thank you for the help!

Comment: ... When are you reading into `num1` and `num2`? It looks like you are assigning the values of the text fields, not retrieving them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example code, you haven't initialized `num1` and `num2`.  So (if you are using ARC, which is the default for new projects), those variables are initialized to nil.

In Objective-C, you can send any message (like `stringValue` or `intValue`) to nil, and it will return 0 or nil back.  So:

```
NSNumber *num1; // initialized to nil by ARC
NSNumber *num2; // initialized to nil by ARC

// This sets self.addNumberOfRoundsText.text to nil.
self.addNumberOfRoundsText.text = [num1 stringValue];

// This sets self.numberOfRoundsText.text to nil.
self.numberOfRoundsText.text = [num2 stringValue];

// This gets 0 for [num1 intValue] and 0 for [num2 intValue], which add up
// to 0, so sum is an NSNumber representing zero.
NSNumber *sum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([num1 intValue] + [num2 intValue])];
NSLog(@"%@", [sum stringValue]);
```

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to do.  Maybe you have two text fields, and each text field contains a number, and you want to add up those two numbers.  If that's what you want to do, try this:

```
int n1 = self.addNumberOfRoundsText.text.intValue;
int n2 = self.numberOfRoundsText.text.intValue;
int sum = n1 + n2;
NSLog(@"sum = %d", sum);
```

Comment: +1 because you answered my question, you are a bad ass! Thanks bro

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Code as you asked you want to add two `UITextField` Value into one single `String`

```
 NSString* finalSTring;

  finalSTring =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",textfield1.text,textField2.text];
   //textField1 and Textfield2 is instance of TextField.

   NSLog(@"%@",finalSTring);//here you have new Single String
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two text fields: `field1` and `field2`:

```
int sum = [field1.text intValue] + [field2.text intValue];
```

Or if you want sum as an `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber* sum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[field1.text intValue] + [field2.text intValue]];
```

Answer (score 0):

why not to set it like this

```
NSNumber *num1;
NSNumber *num2;
self.addNumberOfRoundsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",num1];
self.numberOfRoundsText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",num2];

NSNumber *sum = num1 + num2 ;
NSLog(@"%@", sum );
```